# JEST toThrow() not throwing error from function inside expect

Tags: javascript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I've got this test setup, where I'm trying to force an error thrown that happens when a click is produced on the element, so I have to render it first, then produce the event that sets off the error. So when I setup the test like so

```
it("should throw error", () => {
    render(
      <Root>
        <Component role='id' />
      </Root>
    );
    const component = screen.getByRole('id');
    if (option) userEvent.click(option);
});
```

it immediately fires the error thrown to console, even without an assertion

But when I tried something like this

```
it("should throw error", () => {
  expect(() => {
    render(
      <Root>
        <Component role='id' />
      </Root>
    );
    const component = screen.getByRole('id');
    if (option) userEvent.click(option);
  }).toThrow(
    'Error msg'
  );
});
```

I get

> Expected substring: "Error msg"
>
> Received function did not throw

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is the error in the first example?

Comment: @evolutionxbox it throws the error I'm expecting ("Error msg")

Comment: Try only wrapping the `userEvent.click()` in your expect statement. You don't need to wrap the entire `render` function. `expect(userEvent.click()).toThrow('msg')`

Comment: @CharlieStanard toThrow() seems to expect a function as the assertion :(

Comment: PS: a function returning `userEvent.click(option)` as the assertion still doesn't throw